# Vite + React not rendering

Tags: reactjs, vite, vite-reactjs

i'm having a very confusing issue with **vite + react**, i initialized a new template via `npm create vite@latest` but the issue is when i start the dev server after all process it does start at localhost, it does show the html file with title Vite + React, and the root element but doesnt render the jsx files... and is giving me a error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.jsx line 7)` any ideas?

Error:

```js
main.jsx:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.jsx:6:61)
```

main.jsx:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this I hope you find it useful.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```